# How do you stop IEx.pry timing out?

Tags: elixir

If I put IEx.pry into my elixir code and then run it with IEx, the breakpoint is hit as expected but it times out after a few seconds.

I know I can adjust the timeout length by passing a number of milliseconds to IEx.pry, but I don't want any timeout at all.

How do I stop it timing out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No timeout in tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321150/no-timeout-in-tests)

Comment: Yes, if it is during tests, the link above is the correct answer.

Comment: @user2355213 please clarify in what conditions are you running the `IEx.pry` and if the linked question solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the linked [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321150/no-timeout-in-tests).

Run the tests with `--trace` option.

```
mix test --trace
```