# Increase timeout period of Elixir IEx.pry session

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I'm trying to increase the timeout period of an IEx.pry session.  Specifically, I'my pry-ing in a Phoenix framework unit test.  I've added the following to the body of my test:

```
require IEx
IEx.pry
```

I looked at the IEx documentation for the `pry` method and it says that the first parameter is a timeout period in milliseconds.  But, when I update the pry call to:

```
IEx.pry(60000)
```

... it still times out in 30 seconds.  How do I increase this timeout period?

### EDIT

For posterity's sake, with Elixir 1.1, you can use the `--trace` flag on your test command and timeout infinity will be used.  For example:

```
$ iex -S mix test test/models/user_test.exs:37 --trace
```

Comment: If @Kernael answered your question you should mark that answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I think I just up-voted his answer without accepting it.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No worries.  Just thought you may not be aware is all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timeout is due to ExUnit, not IEx.pry in itself, see [No timeout in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321150/no-timeout-in-tests)

`ExUnit.configure(timeout: :infinity)`